# How do I change variable colors in a custom theme vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded a theme that looked nice in c. It has red variable colors.
However when I change to python the color are white and I understand there is a way to change that but I dont really know how. I tried it this way but that doesnt work.
[the error and what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF7PY.png)

Comment: you have to use the languageID not the file extension, use `["python"]`, the errors says you can use it on language basis, it makes sense to color a variable the same for all languages, have you checked the TextMate scope of the python variable

Comment: I really dont know what I am doing, just tried some things I found on the internet. Can you tell me what the textmate scope is? And if you know how, can you tell me how to change the variable color from white to red

Comment: search SO for `color customization` or search the VSC docs